# Running a Moodle quiz via API

Tags: moodle-api

I have been asked to see if we can incorporate some of our Moodle quizes on our webpage, and am having issues finding any information on this.

In effect, what I want to do is allow our webserver to request the quiz from the Moodle system, either under a session where the Moodle system supplies the question one by one (preferable in JSON) and receives the answers, or a way to get the full set of questions (and answers including answer type and correct answer) to allow the quiz to be embeded. The webserver will need to know if the test was successful in the end.

I found a couple of articles which eluded to such functionality either being suggests (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Quiz_web_services) and an article which described a model which had been used, but I can find no useful information about how it may be done.